# Можно ли создать sql процедуру с помощью JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java, sql

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий код:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ORDTEST."TO_STRING"(
nt_in in ntt_varchar2, 
delimiter_in IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',')
return varchar2 is
v_idx PLS_INTEGER;
v_str varchar2(32767);
v_dlm VARCHAR2(10);
v_length NUMBER;
v_max_size NUMBER;
begin  
v_dlm := delimiter_in;
v_idx := nt_in.FIRST;
v_max_size :=2000;
WHILE v_idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
  IF (nvl(length(v_str),0) + length(v_dlm) + length(nt_in(v_idx))) > v_max_size THEN 
    if  v_str is null then
      v_str := substr(nt_in(v_idx), 0, v_max_size);
    else
      v_str := v_str || v_dlm || substr(nt_in(v_idx), 0, v_max_size - length(v_str) - length(v_dlm));
    end if;
    EXIT;
  END IF;
  IF (v_str is not null and length(v_str) > 0) THEN
    v_str := v_str || v_dlm || nt_in(v_idx);
  ELSE
    v_str := nt_in(v_idx);
  END IF;
  v_idx := nt_in.NEXT(v_idx);
END LOOP;
RETURN v_str;
end to_string;
```

Получаю в результате java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900: неверно предложение на языке SQL.
Можно ли создавать процедуру через jdbc?
Использую Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, что вы можете написать в файле-скрипте создания базы, можно "запихнуть" в код, а затем выполнить запрос, например, как написано [тут](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-jdbc-java-to-dynamically-create-a-stored-procedure/171).

Если у вас выскакивает такой *эксепшн*, то просто попробуйте запустить ваш скрипт с консоли. Обычно (как в MySql) там уточняется ошибка.